# How does variable expands in makefile?

Tags: variables, makefile, gnu, expansion

In this simple makefile:

```
var = foo

func = $(info $1 -> $($1) )

$(call func, var)
```

I would expect `$($1)` to expand to `foo`, but the output:

```
 var ->
```

Why? and how to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately make's handling of whitespace is inconsistent.  In general the best rule of thumb when writing makefiles is that you should never use whitespace inside variables and functions in places where they're not required.

Here, the problem is that `$(call func, var)` sets `$1` to the value " `var`" (that is, the space is included).  In many situations this is not a problem, but in this case it means when you use `$($1)` it expands to `$( var)` which of course is not a set variable.

If you remove the space:

```
$(call func,var)
```

it will work.

According to the rules make *usually* uses this should not happen because the normal rules for make is that *preceding* whitespace is ignored and *subsequent* whitespace is preserved.  But that rule doesn't seem to be in effect for `call` unfortunately.